# Streadreader adds vbcrlf and quotes to input file

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to read in a html file into my .net app (it's an email template). Problem is when I read it in, .net inserts vbcrlf (which I can fix) and also replaces every " with a double "" which really screws up the html.

here's the code (simplified to make it easier to read)

```
      Dim obj = WebRequest.Create("http://www.myurl.com/email/standard.htm").GetResponse()
    Dim rdr As New StreamReader(obj.GetResponseStream())
    Dim body As String = rdr.ReadToEnd
```

Now "body" has the html but also has vbcrlf (everywhere) and added double quotes.

```
    vbCrLf & "<!DOCTYPE html>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<html lang=""en"">" & vbCrLf & "<head>" & vbCrLf & "    <title>apptimi</title>" & vbCrLf & "  "
```

Any idea why this is happening?
thanks

Comment: Is there any chance the page renderer of whatever is hosting that URL is doing it?  What are you using to examine the contents of `body` ? Could that be falsely injecting the junk?

Comment: It's possible. It's hosted on a .net site on Azure so possibly the http rendering engine there is inserting the additional "stuff". I'm viewing the data in Visual Studio debugger but I've checked that's it's not falsely injecting the junk. Anyway I've solved the problem by just finding and removing the junk but it puzzles me as to there it is coming from. thanks.

Comment: You're deceiving yourself if you're looking at that in Quick Watch or by setting a breakpoint and hovering `body` to see the value.  The IDE is doing that.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `WebClient` to get the HTML.

```
 Dim html As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.myurl.com/email/standard.htm")
```

**Or alternative depending on framework you are targeting**

```
Dim html As String = Await New WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.myurl.com/email/standard.htm")
```

You didn't mention what you want to do with this, but if you want to parse the HTML then I would look at HTMLAgilityPack ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried that and it comes out exactly the same! Same vbcrlf and same double quotes. I suspect the issue is deep in the bowels of .net and both functions end up using the same code somewhere.

Comment: Not sure then, I was able to download more than a few sites and it didn't replace anything...

Answer (score 0):

You're deceiving yourself if you're looking at that in Quick Watch or by setting a breakpoint and hovering `body` to see the value. The IDE is doing that. The VbCrLf's are the IDE's representation of the NewLines that are in the HTML.  The doubled double quotes are the IDE's indicators...they aren't really there.

Console Application:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim html As String = New Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.myurl.com/email/standard.htm")

    Console.WriteLine(html)

    Console.Write("Done . . . ")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Compare the IDE's version in Quick Watch window with what appears in the console output...the latter is reality.

Mark Codexer's answer as the Correct Answer, not mine...he earned it.

Comment: Thanks. You could be right. I'll check it today and see what's really happening.